# Merging multiple rasters (Very large dataset)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic, large-datasets, mosaic-dataset

I am working on project to create a DSM raster for whole Kentucky. I will have over 46000 tiff tiles and each one is about 10 Mb and one band. Normally, I use *Mosaic to New Raster Tool* but this time data is very large. I am planning to divide the project into smaller pieces but I have no idea what size should I set the each piece. 
I will use python code with ArcGis Desktop 10.6 to complete project. Considering my computer has 2.7 Ghz (i7) processor with 16 Gb RAM, How many tiles I need to use at one time? like 1000? 10000? or what number?

Comment: Create a _mosaic dataset_, should be able to deal with that number of rasters.

Comment: Don't use a raster catalog, it is inferior to a Mosaic Dataset as @Hornbydd suggests http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000037000000 . On the surface they appear similar; a Mosaic Dataset is like an unmanaged image catalog. With 46k tiles of 10MB, which is considerably large but not the largest I've dealt with, you should be able to create a dataset in less than a day and it will be usable *just like a single raster*. If you do need to combine to a single raster you can use raster to other format, be prepared for that to take 2-3 days depending on your HDD speed.

Comment: Thank you @Micheal Stimson and Hornbydd . I will create mosaic dataset and keep it that way.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include a single, focused question?